# MATLAB Mex: retrieving a logical from a struct in MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab, struct, mex

I have a struct created in this way:

`testStruct = struct; testStruct.tf = true`.

And I want to pass this struct into my c++ code through mex, this is a snapshot of what I did:

```
mxArray *mxValue; 
mxValue = mxGetField(prhs[0], 0, "tf");
mxLogical tf = mxGetLogicals(mxValue);
mexPrintf("tf: %i \n", tf);
```

Whether I set `testStruct.tf` to `true` or `false`, it prints `tf: 1`. I also tested it with an if condition and the if condition gets executed regardless of what logical I put in.

I tried `bool tf = mxGetLogicals(mxValue)`, but that wasn't useful.

Can I get a pointer on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I get a **pointer** on this?

... That is kind of the problem ... `mxGetLogical` returns a Pointer to the first logical element in the mxArray. [see documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetlogicals.html).

So try this (compiled as mexTest):

```
#include "mex.h"
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] )
{ 
  mxArray *mxValue; 
  mxLogical *tf;  
  mxValue = mxGetField(prhs[0], 0, "tf");
  tf = mxGetLogicals(mxValue);    
  mexPrintf("tf: %i \n", *tf);  
}
```

Running it gives me these resutls:

```
>> testStruct.tf = true;
>> mexTest(testStruct)
tf: 1 
>> testStruct.tf = false;
>> mexTest(testStruct)
tf: 0
```